# QTP Framework to automate Cognos Reports testing

Tags: testing, frameworks, automation, qtp, cognos

I am in the process of automating a testing/comparing of 2 Cognos Reports outputs using QTP (v11). In the current solution, due to the different data sets, I had to hard code QTP variables to compare 2 static reports.

Is there a generic solution/approach that any of you have used to automate reports testing in general and Cognos reports in particular?

If interested I can share the current solution in place, but I am looking for a more generic approach.

Kindly help if you have any idea.

Comment: If you share your current solution, we might have a chance to evaluate it and make suggestions. If not, not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two seperate enviroments Cognos environments you may use Cognos Lifecycle Manager. It automatically validates reports and compares output even between different Cognos versions.